# Update client-side information from server, without sending a request each time

Tags: node.js, time, server, server-side, client-side

I am currently developing my own desktop clock app and after successfully receiving the current date and time via custom API and locally, I've come to the point where
serious complications may occur in the future.

With the current implementation of (local-time), the time is updated locally - every minute per app instance.

It would be unnecessary silly if I try to achieve the same for the (server-time) -> to send a GET request each minute to the Server from every existing app instance...

So, here comes my question..

**What are the more efficient alternatives**?

P.S. The server environment is Node.js. 
     The received time is in the form of a JSON.

Comment: when ever your app start get the time from the server and then start the count from this time

Comment: Hey @Amit Wagner, thanks for the suggestion, I've thought of it, but Imagine the case of the Daylight saving time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this code

```js
const serverTime = new Date(); // lets say this is time from server

const timer = (time) =>{
  setTimeout(()=>{
      time.setSeconds(time.getSeconds() + 1);
      console.log(time)
      timer(time);
  },1000)
}
timer(serverTime);
```